# Swift dynamic variable for a generic class

Tags: swift, generics, dynamic

When I do the below:

```
@objc dynamic var notifierData: NotifierData<ModelTypeStruct>
```

NotifierData is a class type, ModelTypeStruct is a struct. I get a compile time error when adding observer,

```
observer = observe(\.notifierData ...
```

saying

> Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath
>   Swift.ReferenceWritableKeyPath<

I suspect the issue if due to have a generic dynamic type, do you know a work around this? many thanks, swift 4

[image]

Comment: Try using `observer = observe(\YOUR_CLASS_NAME.notifierData ...`

Comment: dynamic generic value does not seem to be accessible with objc c